# Бот vk_api отвечает бесконечное число раз на 1 сообщение

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Нужно чтобы он отвечал **один** раз, а не бесконечно.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import vk_api
vk = vk_api.VkApi(login = 'login', password = 'password')
#vk_api.VkApi(token = 'a02d...e83fd') #Авторизоваться как сообщество
vk.auth()
values = {'out': 0,'count': 100,'time_offset': 60}

def write_msg(user_id, s):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id':user_id,'message':s})

while True:
    response = vk.method('messages.get', values)
    if response['items']:
        values['last_message_id'] = response['items'][0]['id']
    for item in response['items']:
        if response['items'][0]['body'] == 'privet':
             write_msg(item['user_id'],'privet')
        else:
             write_msg(item['user_id'],'pishite privet takimi bukvami')

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Накидал пример бота, отвечающего на последнее полученное сообщение

```
import traceback
import time

import vk_api


LOGIN = '<LOGIN>'
PASSWORD = '<PASSWORD>'


vk = vk_api.VkApi(login=LOGIN, password=PASSWORD)
vk.auth()

# Ограничение бота, чтобы он не отвечал на свои же сообщения
# Для снятие ограничения: bot_user_id = None
rs = vk.method('users.get')
bot_user_id = rs[0]['id']

last_message_bot_id = None

messages_get_values = {
    'out': 0,
    'count': 1,
    'time_offset': 60,
    'version': '5.67'
}

while True:
    try:
        rs = vk.method('messages.get', messages_get_values)
        print(rs)

        # Если ничего не пришло
        if not rs['items']:
            continue

        message_id = rs['items'][0]['id']
        from_user_id = rs['items'][0]['user_id']

        # Не будем отвечать на собственное сообщение
        if from_user_id == bot_user_id:
            continue

        message = rs['items'][0]['body']
        print('    From user #{}, message (#{}): "{}"'.format(from_user_id, message_id, message))

        message = 'Получена команда: "{}"'.format(message)
        last_message_bot_id = vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': from_user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': vk_api.utils.get_random_id()})

        messages_get_values['last_message_id'] = last_message_bot_id

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error:', traceback.format_exc())

    finally:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, эта ошибка происходит из-за того, что вы не [помечаете сообщение прочитанным](https://vk.com/dev/messages.markAsRead). Также при отправке сообщения используйте [random_id](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send):

> Уникальный (в привязке к API_ID и ID отправителя) идентификатор,
>   предназначенный для предотвращения повторной отправки одинакового сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Используй longpool, он будет последовательно получать сообщения и сразу на них отвечать, что исключит вероятность повторного ответа на слово-триггер.